# How can I copy the position, scale and rotation of points in grease pencil to selectted frames?

Tags: grease-pencil

I tried some animation with grease pencil more or less successfull. But now I encountered an isssue. I want to edit a point e.g in frame 7 and this should also appear in the following frames.
But I don't want to step through every frame and readjust the points.

Is there some "Blender secret" which I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Enable multiframe editing:

[image]

Select frames, that you want to edit:

[image]

Select points that you want to edit:

[image]

And do modifications with all points in the selected frames in the same time